# Removing once from C++ List

Tags: c++

I have the following example:

```
// remove from list
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int myints[]= {17,89,89,7,14};
  list<int> mylist (myints,myints+5);

  mylist.remove(89);

  cout << "mylist contains:";
  for (list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
        cout << " " << *it;
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
17, 7, 14
```

The problem with this is that it removes both instances of 89. 
Is there any easy way to just remove one instance of 89?

Comment: erase requires iterators

Comment: @Lorlin I keep forgetting stl things Oo , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You might do however:

```
mylist.erase(find(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), 89));
```

Comment: `std::list` has no member function `find`.

Comment: eq: find is in <algorithm> not a member of list.

Comment: Remember to check the result of `find` before calling `erase`.

Comment: Works. Thanks! Just a reminder to add #include <algorithm> too =)

Comment: *"No, there isn't"* - Well, in fact there is, since what you describe is a pretty easy and idiomatic way.

Comment: @ChristianRau Regarding to readability of the code it doesn't seem an elegant solution. While scanning the code, you need a moment to decipher the line in contrary to the  ``mylist.remove(89)`` which is obvious. Testing the ``find`` result for null requires splitting the code line, which, in my opinion is a failure to describe this simple operation elegantly.

Comment: So just write a function and call "remove(mylist, 89)". Then it's elegant at the point of use..